# Setting default value when sorting by association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Background:

I'm working on making a simple clone of Hacker News using Rails and Postgres. I've got most everything finished, and I'm currently working on allowing a visitor to the site sort the articles by its score. As it stands at the moment, I have it *mostly* working. Here's the relevant code:

`Article.select("articles.*, SUM( CASE votes.is_up WHEN FALSE THEN -1 ELSE 1 END ) AS score")
  .joins("LEFT JOIN votes ON articles.id = votes.votable_id AND votes.votable_type = 'Article'")
  .group("articles.id")
  .order("score DESC")`

As you may be able to tell, this has one problem: articles with no score are not properly sorted (at least one problem anyways--I'm not a SQL pro by any means). For example, if I have articles with scores 2, -1, 5 and 0, the order will be `0, 5, 2, -1`, rather than the correct order of `5, 2, 0, -1`.

Question:

I recognize that the easiest/best way to do this may be to just put a `score` column on `articles`--and I very well may go that route--but this has made me very curious: is there any way to give a default `score` of 0 to `articles` with no associated `votes`?

Update 1:

Based on the suggestions, I've changed my select statement to:

`Article.select("articles.*, COALESCE( SUM( CASE votes.is_up WHEN FALSE THEN -1 ELSE 1 END ), 0) AS score")`

This, however, hasn't changed the result at all.

Update 2:

The SQL generated when I run my query:

`SELECT  articles.*, COALESCE(SUM( CASE votes.is_up WHEN FALSE THEN -1 ELSE 1 END ), 0) AS score 
FROM "articles" LEFT JOIN votes ON articles.id = votes.votable_id AND votes.votable_type = 'Article'
GROUP BY articles.id
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 20
OFFSET 0`

You can also see the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` that I use for pagination--I didn't mention this originally because I expected it to not be relevant.

Comment: Do a left outer join and `coalesce((sum(votes), 0)`

Comment: I've never come across `coalesce` before, thanks! From looking at the Postgres docs, it definitely looks like what I'd want.

Where are you suggesting putting the left join?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're just getting NULL, so you need a `COALESCE` to convert it to 0;

```
Article.select(
  "articles.*, COALESCE(SUM( CASE votes.is_up WHEN FALSE THEN -1 ELSE 1 END ), 0) AS score")
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Using `COALESCE` definitely seems like the right way to go. However, I'm getting the exact same behavior as before, which, after looking at the Postgres docs, I find surprising. Any thoughts?

Comment: @aandrea Sounds very strange. Could you somehow see the generated SQL?

Comment: I updated the main post with the generated SQL. Thanks again!